# Windows 7 - LAN disconnects automatically after locking

Tags: windows-7, lan

Some weeks ago, Windows 7 started to disconnect me from my LAN whenever I'm away from my computer. I've set it to lock my session after five minutes and turn off the screen at that time. After those five minutes have passed, the LAN adapter loses connectivity as well. It automatically reconnects when I unlock the computer. It does however not disconnect when I manually lock the session with Win+L.

I've already turned off the power saving option for this adapter, and I'm using the default "balanced" power plan. Interestingly, it only seems to happen on my home network (which I also have not modified recently) when using my laptop's docking station (can't use the built-in port while it's docked), not with other wired networks.

**Edit:** The problem seems to disappear when I disable the power option to turn off the screen after five minutes. However, I very much would like to keep this option enabled, so I'd like to understand how this option has anything to do with my LAN adapter.

Comment: Quick googling seems to indicate this might be a driver issue. Barring that, I would look for any specialty software on the PC that might be the culprit.

Comment: I would have expected something similar, but I haven't updated my drivers since 2013 - because there are simply no newer ones for my laptop.

Comment: It seems like a Windows update might have introduced and also fixed this behaviour - I can no longer reproduce it on the same machine.

Comment: After physically rearranging my desk, including cables, this (and another related issue - LAN disconnecting when a lightswitch is pressed) started happening again. I had the idea that it might be a physical problem with the LAN cable, and indeed, after rearranging the cable yet another time, the issue is gone again, as weird as it sounds. Maybe there is some interferrence between the laptop display and the cable, which is 10+ meters long.